# How to add variables to the data factory ARM Template

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I've got a data factory with 3 variables in the main pipeline.

These variables contain environment settings, so I'd therefore like them to be exposed to the ARM template. When I import the ARM template to a new environment, they are not in the variables list, only "factoryid" is shown.

[image]

I tried to add `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` (shown below) to my master branch, but it did not make a difference. This was recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422611/3932615)

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
"properties": {
    "variables":{
        "*":{
            "defaultValue":"="
        }
    }
}
```

}

How do I get my variables recognized, so that I can set up environment configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not so bad. Please double-check whether you don't make any mistake:
1) The file must be located in the root folder and named exactly: **arm-template-parameters-definition.json**
[image]
2) Verify if your file contains all necessary brackets and structure reflects what you're looking for parametrise:

```
{
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
        "properties": {
            "variables": {
                "*": {
                    "defaultValue": "="
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3) Make sure that the file has been pushed to the repo and is present over there.
4) Remember that you must click **Publish** in ADF Designer (Author) to regenerate ARM templates
5) All changes go to **adf-publish** branch. Do you check the regenerated files exactly in *that branch*?

---

Let me show you my extremely simple example.
a) Pipeline *PL_SimpleCopy* with variable *DbUser*
[image: Pipeline]
b) File: *arm-template-parameters-definition.json*

```
{
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
        "properties": {
            "variables": {
                "DbUser": {
                    "defaultValue": "=:-DbUserValue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

c) ARM Template in *ADF_Publish* branch. Selected section is a parameter that you need:
[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I thought should happen, however I still can't see it in the template. I've tried deleting the contents of the adf_publish branch to force it to regenerate, but I still get a template wirthout my variables in.

Comment: Actually, it looks like this worked, but it's removed the parameters for all the linked services. SO now I can't repoint them to the new environment

Comment: I can't explain why it wasn't working, but it seems to be now. In addition to the above, I found that I needed to augment this solution with the "Default" template that Microsoft silently applies. This can be found here -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#default-parameterization-template Combining the two gets you both sets of parameters/variables

Answer (score -1):

You can add parameters to your Azure data factory by having a parameters JSON file and deploying the ADF with the parameters as follows :

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyARMDeployment -ResourceGroupName ADFTutorialResourceGroup -TemplateFile C:\ADFTutorial\ADFTutorialARM.json -TemplateParameterFile C:\ADFTutorial\ADFTutorialARM-Parameters.json
For more information, please refer the following doc :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template#parameters-json

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does adding a parameter to the file map onto a pipeline parameter? Is there a reference or naming convention required?

Comment: Hey Neil, Please refer to the following post for an alternate approach :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58165127/10653466